# python 2.7.6 issue for in for issue bug

Tags: python, traceback

hi i write these code in python 2.7.6 
but wont execute correctly and alwayse give me error ...
Please Help me

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    channel=None
    devices = finddevices()
    for d in devices:
        ser=findservices(d[0])
        for s in ser:
            print s
            if 'OBEX Object Push' in s[2]:
                channel=s[1]
        obex.sendfile(d[0], channel, '/home/mobile.jar')
```

and out :

```
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 2, 'Headset Gateway')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 3, 'Handsfree Gateway')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 4, 'Sim Access Server')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 23, 'AV Remote Control Target')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 25, 'Advanced Audio')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 15, 'Android Network Access Point')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 15, 'Android Network User')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 19, 'OBEX Phonebook Access Server')
('00:E3:B2:0C:2E:2B', 12, 'OBEX Object Push')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abbas/workspace/Bluetooth Module/package/test.py", line 21, in <module>
    obex.sendfile(d[0], channel, '/home/abbas/mobile.jar')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/lightblue/_obex.py", line 234, in sendfile
    raise TypeError("channel must be int, was %s" % type(channel))
TypeError: channel must be int, was <type 'NoneType'>
```

why my channel is none ?
why my if condition is not True ?

Comment: Three possibilites: The `s[1]` is `None`, the condition is always `False`, or `channel` changed somehow in a code which isn't shown. Try printing `channel` *right* before the `sendfile` call.

Comment: according to the log, s[1] appears to be 12, and the condition appears to be True

Comment: @njzk2 I just edited that haha. Added a third possibility.

Comment: i confused !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
when i run this script in debug mod and set break piont .. All things right and every think work fine !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't actually send the file once, and then on the next device, fail? For example: on the first device, everything works fine and you print out the various items returned by `findservices()`. But on the second device, your `findservices()` call returns an empty list, so the inner for-loop never executes, and you jump directly to the `obex.sendfile()` call, which fails with the error you see.